# getting model instance from ngrx store select

Tags: angular, ngrx

When selecting an object from ngrx store we don't get an instance of the class but an object with the same properties. This prevents from calling a function on the object.

Should I create an instance inside the subscibe function? I'm just wondering that I havn't found anything on this topic and want to know what is best practise.

```
class ItemModel {
  name: string;

  formatedName() {
    return this.name.upperCass(); // always undefined
  }
}

class AnyClass {
  item: ItemModel; 

  construtor() {
    this.store.select(state => state.item).subscribe(item => this.item = item);
  }

  func() {
    this.item.formatedName();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your code-snipped there is at least one issue:
You need to use `this` for the name.

```
formatedName() {
    return >>this.<<name.toUpperCase(); // always undefined
}
```

(Not sure if this was just in your snipped here on SO or also in your code.

---

**But:** It is generally not recommended to have Class-Instances in the store, there are a few rules of thumb:

1. The store-content should serializable without any major modifications (=> just use Object and Primitives)
2. ngrx (and rxjs in general) are relying heavily on functional programming patterns, so mixing it Object Oriented paradigms is not recommended.

Since you did not provide any further details I have to assume that your specific case is about formatting a string (e.g. to uppercase), I would suggest you to use a template-pipe for that:

```
<span>{{item | myFormatToUpperCasePipe}}</span>
```

and I'd go even one step further and utilize the `async`-Pipe as well:

```
class MyComponent {
    item$ = this.store.select(state => state.item);
}

// template:
<span>{{item$ | async | myFormatToUpperCasePipe}}</span>
```

In a case where you do not need this information in a template, my question would be: Why do you need to format something that is not displayed in the UI?
But even in this case I'd suggest you to keep the functional patterns and use utility-methods to transform data - possibly even as part of an rxjs-stream.

Comment: Thanks. The uppercase function was just an example to keep the question simple. I have a model with a lot of values. Some are calculated on the base of other values. I don't want to have this logic inside the component because it is used in multiple components. I don't want to use a pipe because it is not only displayed in the UI but also sent to a server. So putting this into the model and write a `get` function seemed correct and worked fine until I used the store.

Comment: But I see your point so maybe I will write static functions to calculate the values.

Comment: If you have many calculated field and need the calculated values in many places maybe you can setup a mapping stream `store.select(..item).map(toFormattedItem).subscribe(...)` -> as a beneficial side-effect: `toFormattedItem()` will be super-easy to write unit-tests for